# Openrewrite: Run unit test in the IDE (IntelliJ) that uses classes from the same multiproject (not packages in a jar)

Tags: intellij-idea, openrewrite

My unit test in `optaplanner-rewrite` has this code using OpenRewrite bom 1.11.0:

```
@Override
public void defaults(RecipeSpec spec) {
    spec.recipe(new AsConstraintBuilder())
            .parser(JavaParser.fromJavaVersion()
                    .classpath("optaplanner-core"));
}
```

and it runs fine in Maven.

But when I run the unit test in my IDE (IntelliJ), I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find runtime dependencies beginning with: 'optaplanner-core'

    at org.openrewrite.java.JavaParser.dependenciesFromClasspath(JavaParser.java:97)
    at org.openrewrite.java.JavaParser$Builder.classpath(JavaParser.java:250)
```

This is because my IDE window has a multiproject open, that includes both `optaplanner-core` and `optaplanner-rewrite`. There is no `optaplanner-core.jar` in the classpath of my test run, only `optaplanner-core/target/classes`.

How do I run my unit test in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a proper solution, but as a workaround you should be able to load the entire classpath like this:

```java
    @Override
    public void defaults(RecipeSpec spec) {
        List<Path> classpath = new ClassGraph().getClasspathURIs().stream().map(Paths::get).toList();
        spec.recipe(new AsConstraintBuilder())
            .parser(JavaParser.fromJavaVersion()
                    .classpath(classpath));
    }
```

Comment: This workaround works! (After I refreshed IntelliJ's maven synchronization)

Comment: I created a PR to fix the problem so no workaround is needed: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/pull/2407

Comment: Merged for openrewrite bom 1.12.0 I believe.